# How can I check the values of existing data with unknown keys in a Firebase rule?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Using Firebase security rules, how can I check sibling values to determine whether or not `newData` is valid?

In my app each `game` has list of `moves`. Here the game is `1405584062293`:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Eu4B1Qt.png]

When a new move is submitted, I want to validate it with reference to the moves that have already been played. For starters, a player should only be able to play every second move (player one can play even moves starting at index `0`, player two can play odd moves).

Since each move's key is an unknown random string (as per [this recommendation in the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html)) I don't know how to check the previous move. I also don't know how to count the number of existing moves.

Here's my structure:

```
{
  "rules":{
    ".read":true,
    "games":{
      "$game":{
        "moves":{
          "$move":{
            ".write":"auth !== null",
            // Something along these lines would get me going...
            ".validate":"data.parent().keys.count % 2 == 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In reality the rules of the game are far more complex and I expect I'll need to use Firesafe or a similar solution, but for now I'd like to know how to achieve these and other such simple rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every use case can fit into a single, recommended approach for managing generic lists. Certainly not yours. You would probably find more use in [an incremental ID](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/B78Ce/) approach.

Since you can't do a contains on child record keys/values, you'll maintain a value that can be incremented. For example, utilizing the incremental ID approach above, I could then write a security rule to make sure I'm writing to odd keys (and only on my turn) as follows:

```
".validate": "((root.child('counter').val()||0)+1) % 2 === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('evenOrOdd').val()"
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I actually ended up solving my problem by simply choosing the id's of moves (`move-0`, `move-1`, `move-2`...), and since it's reasonable to assume that the players will have the complete list of moves for a game there's no need for a counter. Everything's working now.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not undo moves (e.g. remove moves from the list in Firebase) there is nothing wrong with storing it as an array (imo).

Problems arise if you remove an element from an array, because then a number in the indexes will be skipped and Firebase no longer sees it as a array, but an object with numbers for keys.

Comment: There are [several reasons why arrays may be bad choices](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), and that includes any data edited concurrently by multiple users. It's not as simple as never deleting.